# External Javascript library doesn't work after hosting the site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a bit of an odd bug here; I have a simple website (http://davidpuetter.azurewebsites.net/shop.html#) that is supposed to load the JQuery library, and the EasyUI library. The JQuery seems to load just fine, because I have a function to print out "ready" when the page is loaded. What the intended function is, is that I can drag each product seen there onto the shopping cart to the right. This works perfectly fine if I run the html files manually from my computer, but not since it has been hosted.

What's happening here?
Thanks for any help

Comment: Are you seeing any loading errors in the browser network tab?

Comment: No, none. Console doesn't give any errors, network tab says 200 OK to the file

Comment: Have you checked to make sure your hosting didn't apply some sort of compiler or filter to the page (just make sure all of your code looks like it should html and js source files)? I don't know that that's the case it's just something to check.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On line 7 in `scripts/shop.js` you are calling `$("#shop").load("shopcontent/cat1.html");`, but it has not loaded yet when you run `$(".item").draggable({` on line 27.

When that lines is executed there are no elements with the class `item` in the document.

My guess is that `$("#shop").load(..` is synchronous when running in `file://`. It is obviously not synchronous when loading over the wire.

You should wait for `.load` to complete (callback) before you call `.draggable`. See [docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Comment: It wouldn't be synchronous it's just the local host is fast enough that it doesn't matter

Comment: I see, thank you. What would the best approach for me to make sure my content gets loaded before the script gets executed?

Comment: This question was marked as a duplicate, so check out the previous answer.

Comment: Okay I had a read through it, but I'm finding it somewhat hard to understand the syntax of the `.on()` function. I'm not sure how to get it to work with the `draggable` function, because it's not a native JQuery function. I've tried doing `$('body').on('draggable', '.item', function() { //old function in here });`, but that doesn't work (console says that it doesnt recognize the `:`.)

Comment: You can wait for the callback of `.load` before you call `.draggable`. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found your problem. If you break at line 27 in shop.js, reload the page and check the value of $(".item") in the console, you'll find that it returns an empty array. You're going to have to initialize the items before calling draggable on them.